# Is There A Way to See Users Ranked by Questions or Answers?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, users

We can see users ranked by reputation totals, but I can't find a display like that for number of questions asked or number of answers given.

Is there a way to see a display of users sorted in number of questions or answers?

Comment: There is for a given tag, or one can pull it from the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You've got to be in the lead for *[number of questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway?tab=questions&sort=newest)!*

Comment: @Wikis: That just means I know less than everyone else and have more to learn!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go :

- [Top 25 users by number of answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/43808/top-answerers)
- [Top 100 users by number of questions asked](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/44871/top-question-askers)

Comment: Bah! I was in the lead for a long time!

Comment: Is this all time or only since a certain date?  My [own page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tangooversway?tab=questions&sort=newest) shows 224 questions, but your second link there shows 122 questions.

Comment: @TangoOversway as you could see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/queries), the most recent data dump is feb 2.